# Interpretation of logistic regression model output in R

Tags: r, logistic

I have created a model in logistic regression to find if there is an association between the number of months of drug use prior to rehab, and the success of that rehab. My code is:

```
head(peermentor)
summary(peermentor)
sapply(peermentor$duration_use, sd)
xtabs(~duration_use + rehab_success, data = peermentor)
peermentor$rehab_success <- factor(peermentor$rehab_success)
mylogit <- glm(duration_use ~ rehab_success, data = peermentor)
summary(mylogit)
```

And the output is:

```
Call:
glm(formula = duration_use ~ rehab_success, data = peermentor)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-18.966  -12.966   -4.981    5.034  101.034 



Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       18.9665     0.8773  21.618   <2e-16 ***
rehab_successYes  -2.9854     1.1820  -2.526   0.0117 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 298.6489)

    Null deviance: 259341  on 863  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 257435  on 862  degrees of freedom
AIC: 7380.1
```

In interpreting this, is the coefficient of -2.9854 telling us that the greater the number of months of use, there is a -2.9854 change in the log odds of passing the rehab therapy (coded as yes/no)? Does that mean there is a decrease due to the negative sign? Additionally, surely the p value of 0.0117 suggest this is statistically significant? Please also advise on if there is a better statistical model that can be used to find any correlation here

---

Edited code:

```
Call:
glm(formula = rehab_success ~ duration_use, family = binomial(), 
    data = peermentor)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.341  -1.263   1.026   1.070   1.453  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.377679   0.097586   3.870 0.000109 ***
duration_use -0.009959   0.003986  -2.498 0.012473 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1188.8  on 863  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1182.4  on 862  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1186.4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Comment: I think your model should be the other way around: `mylogit <- glm(rehab_success ~ duration_use, data = peermentor)` and if your outcome, `rehab_success` is binary you probably want to set the `family` to `binomial()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have added the new output in the original post. So, now that we have this new output, how would I go about interpreting this?

Comment: try reading this maybe https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The estimated coefficient for the intercept, 0.377679, is the log odds of `rehab_success` being `Yes` when `duration_use` is equal to zero. A value of zero for `duration_use` might not make sense in your sample, since presumably it will never be negative and is always far above zero, and if so, you might want to consider centering `duration_use` so that a zero value for the centered variable is more meaningful.

The estimate for `duration_use` of -0.009959 means that a 1 unit (ie. 1 month according to the information in the question) increase in `duration_use` is associated with a 0.009959 decrease in the log-odds of `rehab_success` being `Yes`, compared to `rehab_success` being `No`. If we exponentiate this number then we obtain the odds ratio of 0.9901, which means that for a 1 month increase in `duration_use` we expect to see (approximately) a 1% decrease in the odds of `rehab_success` being `Yes` and this is statistically significant at the 5% level. Whether it is practically significant/meaningful is a different matter entirely.

I assume that each row in your data is for different participant, if you have repeated measures then you need to use a different approach.

I have some experience in the addiction field (see the google scholar link in my bio if interested), and I believe you might want to allow for a non-linear association of length of use with rehab success. You could do this using non-linear terms in the model, or even better, with splines. You appear to have over 860 subjects, so you might also want to consider adopting a structural equation modelling (SEM) approach and fit a latent class model, which allows for different types of association (ie. different shapes of curves) where each type is grouped into its own class.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks very much for the detailed response. It's always nice to see a fellow medical statistician/epidemiologist. I will certainly check out some of your work. Thank you!